# .NET Core : migrations and registrations of services

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

In my ASP.NET Core app, I have an extension in a specific project that registers all repositories:

```
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(item => item.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
            .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>)) && !item.IsAbstract && !item.IsInterface)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(assignedTypes =>
            {
                 var serviceType = assignedTypes.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>));
                 services.AddScoped(serviceType, assignedTypes);
             });
```

This would register all `IRepository` to their specific implementations.

Now, if I comment out this piece of code, I can add a database migration; yet if I uncomment it, an error will be thrown on running `add-migration`:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.
>
> Error: Cannot instantiate implementation type '`Infrastructure.Repository<T>`' for service type '`Infrastructure.Interfaces.IRepository<T>`'.
>
> Unable to create an object of type '`ApplicationDbContext`'.
>
> For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Any tips for this?

Comment: May I ask why you're using the Generic Repository Antipattern here?

Comment: As a general tip, avoid using the `List<T>.ForEach()` method (because it isn't a real control-structure, and using it means creating a closure with (potentially expensive) captures. Instead, stick to `foreach( var x in y )` - and if you use `foreach()` then you don't need the `ToList()` step either. And other reasons too: Eric Lippert (one of C#'s original language designers) explains here: https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: Also... using dynamic registration of all types that implement some interface is also an anti-pattern in of itself, because you lose all of the _static guarantees_ that a traditional or otherwise _normal_ `ConfigureServices` method has - including not-crashing-due-to-overlooked-services. You should also use `ValidateOnBuild`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceprovideroptions.validateonbuild - e.g. if you have 2 implementations of the same service interface in the same Assembly then that will fail _by surprise_ only at runtime.

Comment: The idea was to generic repo as a base repository to any kind of entity - so the antipattern that you mention. feel free to suggest other approach.

Comment: Don't do that. Doing so doesn't actually solve any real problems, adds unnecessary layers of abstraction, and just makes up more work. Your `DbSet<T>` collections **already are** your Repositories and your `DbContext` is your unit-of-work. Don't reinvent the wheel. The (better) alternative is far simpler: just use your `DbContext` subclass and `DbSet<T>` collections _as-is_ without abstracting over them. (though this is unrelated to your issue).

Comment: The anti-pattern argument about generic repositories is extremely opinionated. If it works for you, then great, if not, then change it. Don't stress about anyone calling it an anti-pattern, especially on SO.

Comment: @mxmissile I don't deny I am very opinionated :)